# Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'csv-parse/sync'

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am using Firebase functions to build an API that parses CSV files.

When I try to use csv-parse/sync instead of csv-parse, my deploy to Firebase Functions fail with the following error:

```
Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'csv-parse/sync''
Require stack:
- /Users/xxx/Programming/xxx/Firebase Functions/xxx/functions/lib/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/runtimes/node/triggerParser.js

Try running "npm install" in your functions directory before deploying.
```

I have imported using:

`import { parse } from 'csv-parse/sync';`

Then use in code like this:

```
interface EventData {
    update: string;
    id: string;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    category: string;
    ages: string;
    place: string;
    placeCoordinate: string;
    startDate: string;
    startTime: string;
    length: string;
    url: string;
    arrName: string;
  }

let events: Array<EventData> = []
const headers = ["update", "id", "title", "description", "ages", "place", "placeCoordinate", "startDate", "startTime", "length", "url", "arrEpost", "arrName", "validated", "skugg"]
try {
    events = parse(text, {columns: headers, from: 6, quote: "\"", delimiter: ";", ltrim: true, rtrim: true})
}...
```

I have installed by going to /functions-folder and running

`npm install --save csv-parse`

Deploying in root folder with

`firebase deploy`

Is this an issue with the framework, with firebase or am I doing something wrong? Normal use of "csv-parse" without sync works just fine. In both cases it seems to import just fine in Visual Studio Code, but not when deploying with "sync". I have tried to clean the node_modules folder, rebuild the package-lock.json-file, upgraded to the latest version of firebase tools, all without success.

I have added a similar question on the framework project issues page: https://github.com/adaltas/node-csv/issues/323

Comment: Please provide the following information:
- package.json `engines.node` and `scripts.build`
- tsconfig.json `target` and `module`
- firebase.json `functions.predeploy`

Comment: Could you tell us which verison of nodejs you're using and what version of csv-parse is installed?

Answer (score 11):

If you are using Typescript you can do

```
import  parse  from 'csv-parse/sync';
```

or

```
import  {parse}  from 'csv-parse/lib/sync';
```

Comment: Had a similar problem with importing `csv-parse/sync` locally in JS and the second option worked for me.

Comment: This is not in the documentation but I think this is the best solution.

Comment: The second option works for me as well (using Typescript), but can anybody explain _why_ it works, and how should I know??

Comment: Only this worked for me in Bun: `import parse from 'csv-parse/lib/sync'`

Answer (score 2):

For me either of the two worked in **node.js** *(based on [Jeff Paredes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71323997/6710876) answer)*:

```js
import parse from 'csv-parse/lib/sync';
```

```
const parse = require('csv-parse/lib/sync');
```

It seems like the folder structure within the `node_modules` folder was changed. So instead of `sync.js` being located in `csv-parse` it is now in `csv-parse/lib`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `csv@6.3.3` (and after having tried using `csv-parser` on its own unsuccesfully), the following is the only combination that worked for me:

```
import { parse } from "csv-parse/sync";
```

Example usage:

```
import * as fs from "fs";
import { parse } from 'csv-parse/sync';

const csvPath = "./data/users.csv";

type UserRow = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
};

const csvContent = fs.readFileSync(csvPath, "utf-8");
const rows: UserRow[] = parse(csvContent, {
  columns: true,
  skip_empty_lines: true,
});

console.log(rows);
```

I also had to add `"moduleResolution": "node"` to the `compilerOptions` of `tsconfig.json`.

Answer (score -1):

As of today, if you install you should just install node-csv by running `yarn add csv` or `pnpm install csv` or `npm install csv`

Then in your code just do

```
import { parse } from 'csv'
```

Then you are done